# ModelBuilder fluent based on POCO Interface partcipation

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to figure out the ModelBuilder/Fluent API so that I can alter properties on entities who underlying CLR type implement a specific interface.

Given an interface such as:

```
public interface IVersionedEntity
{
    DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
}
```

During OnModelCreating I'd like to find any Entities who's underlying CLRType implements this interface, and then alter the ValidFrom and ValidTo properties to be **ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate**.

Basically, I'm looking for the right place to do an "IsAssignableFrom" type test in ModelBuilder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the starting point:

```
var versionedEntityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(type => typeof(IVersionedEntity).IsAssignableFrom(type.ClrType));

foreach (var type in versionedEntityTypes)
{
    type.FindProperty("ValidFrom").ValueGenerated = ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate;
    type.FindProperty("ValidTo").ValueGenerated = ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I actually never saw "ClrType" even though that's eactly what I wanted.